# Send notification to specific user based on their location

Tags: flutter, .net-core, push-notification, geolocation, signalr

The scenario is like that " i have a system let's say it has 10 users. 
And the 10th - i have his location in my database - have made an event in the mobile app.
i want to send a notification to any user in my system within 10km near the 10th user saying "the 10th user have made an event"
What is the best way to implement this scenario ?!
I have read the azure notification hub but couldn't fully understand it.
Note:
I'm have .net core 3.1/ signal-R on the backend
And flutter on the mobile.
And the backend is published on Azure.